# Ubuntu 13.04 makes me restart every time the Internet is down

Tags: windows, internet

I have Ubuntu 13.04, and the same thing happened with ubuntu 13.10. Every time the Internet is slow or down, the system is very slow. I need to restart the notebook or wait for about 15 or 20 minutes for everything to be right again. I have a very bad Internet provider. Besides, the CPU is very hot during these events. It does not happen if I don't go to YouTube, or play Flash games (e.g. on Facebook). If I avoid these things, the connection and the system remain fine.

Comment: internet depends directly on your connection .. So that might be a factor like fluctuating  network , or less network .